# Does Qt's moc Preprocessor Need All C++ Preprocessor Flags

Tags: qt

I noticed that qmake passes all C++ preprocessor flags to the moc utility. I tried moc without these flags on one file and it produced identical results. My question is: would there be cases in which moc would need these flags?

Comment: Do you mean `-D...` defines, or `CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: Here is an example: "moc -DCOMPONENT_LIBRARIESDIR="\"/usr/local/.../lib\"" -DSYSCONF_DATADIR="\"/usr/local/.../etc\"" -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/qt-4.8.0/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../../lng-ide -I/usr/local/qt-4.8.0/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/qt-4.8.0/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/qt-4.8.0/include -I/usr/local/.../include -I/usr/local/...include -I/usr/local/...include -I/usr/local/...include -I. -I. -I../../lng-ide -I. ../diagnosis_viewer.h -o moc_diagnosis_viewer.cpp" &&
"moc ../diagnosis_viewer.h -o moc_diagnosis_viewer.cpp" produced same results.

Comment: On the one hand, preprocessor macros affect the resulting code of the header file, so moc should of course need them. But on the other hand, everything I tried to make my class definition depend on preprocessor macros failed, so for example if you make the names of some slots preprocessor macros, moc would not resolve them. This is somewhat ironic, since moc seems to *not* look at those defines at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moc creates a CPP file which manages the SLOTS and SIGNALS of the class.

if any of those are under preprocessor rules, MOC needs to know about it.
for example:

```
class A {
 Q_OBJECT
public slots:
#ifdef ENABLE_SLOT1
  void slot1();
#endif;
  void slot2();
};
```

if you run moc without a "-DENABLE_SLOT1" parameter then the generated CPP file will not have any idea that it need to generate code handling slot1().