# How does Qt moc handle #ifdef?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, moc

I added some `#ifdef` parts to my code. Now the wanted parts are omitted, but
there are references from the generated moc file to the omitted members, and only from there. Might it happen I need to use #infdef-s in a special way, or not at all? (I did also make a clean build)

It might be the case what happened in [Does Qt's moc Preprocessor Need All C++ Preprocessor Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754007/does-qts-moc-preprocessor-need-all-c-preprocessor-flags)
How can I pass my condition to moc from a CMake build? (I use `#cmakedefine`)

I attempted to use

```
if(My_MODE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DMy_MODE")
endif(My_MODE)
```

but it once results in a warning for the non-moc files, that `My_MODE` is redefined (OK, I can remove #cmakedefine), and second that when compiling the moc file I receive (instead of the linking error) that "no member named X" found in the source file (which is true, but that is why I pass the switch to the compiler).

Comment: You can pass preprocessor directives to `moc`. They are used to preprocess the files - Qt itself uses this to omit some members of the API depending on the platform etc. But you have to make sure, your build environment is adding the right preprocessor directives to the `moc` call.